# Track data changes on tables using doctrine

Tags: mysql, doctrine

So the situation is that I am using Doctrine as the ORM for one of my projects.

Now I want to be able to track the changes happening on certain tables of my website without having to much extra coding for that.

For eg. I have a database which has many tables. out of that i have a table users on which I want to track the changes done
1. users has column name with value 'Raman'
2. Using update sql below i modify the row

`update users set name = 'Raman Joshi' where name='Raman'`

Is there any in built feature in doctrine that allows to create a log table tracking all the data level changes log that was done?

Comment: Always take a look at documentation before asking question. You'll always find solution there if your task is not very complex. Take a look at [this section](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html) of [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/index.html)

Comment: You can install doctrine extentsion: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Doctrine [preUpdate event listener](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate) to do this. Here's a simple example that will send changes to a logger:

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;

class ChangeLoggerListener
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        //find out class and id of object being updated
        $obj=$eventArgs->getEntity();
        $class=get_class($eventArgs->getEntity());
        $id=$obj->getId();
        $log="$class($id) updated: ";

        //find out what has changed...
        $changes=$eventArgs->getEntityChangeSet();
        $separator='';
        foreach ($changes as $field => $values) {
            $log.=$separator."$field changed from {$values[0]} to {$values[1]}";
            $separator=", ";
        }

        //send it to logger
        $this->logger->info($log);
    }
}
```

The manual page shows how to register the listener, but if you're using Symfony, you can register the listener as a service with this in your services.yml

```
my.change_logger:
    class: My\ExampleBundle\Listener\ChangeLoggerListener
    arguments: [@logger]
    tags:
      - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```